# Can you have a public password file that is still secure?

Tags: passwords, password-hashing, dictionary-attack

So I’ve been reading about different ways to store passwords on servers (plain text, encrypted, hashed, hashed + salt, slow hash + salt) and I wanted to find a way where a leak of the stored passwords isn’t an issue without resorting to very slow hashes (since slow hashes means a lot more computer power as people sign in all the time).

So my thought was this:

- User creates a private and public key (where the private key is the password).
- Server stores the public key and uses it to verify the users identity

Now, if there is a 1 to 1 mapping between the private and public key, this is no different than simply storing hashes, since an attacker can just brute force generate public keys just as well as hashes. But if there is a 1 to many mapping between the private key and public key this is no longer the case, since now the attacker has to generate all possible public keys for every given password. This should be possible with for example RSA where you can just add a multiple of the modulus factor and end up with a lot of public keys for a given private key. If you add a random of multiples (say between 1 and N) the attacker has to check all those values right?

So my question is basically if this would work and if it has been done, or if there are better ways to prevent a leaked password file from doing damage.

I also wonder if there’s any better private/public key generation method for this since with RSA you could generate all the different public keys in parallell, in theory making it as fast as simply generating one. If it was an itterative process that would slow down the attacker a lot more.

Edit: I just realized I have overlooked the simple fact that you can just encrypt something and check if the public key decrypts it instead :( Trying to figure out a way around this now.

Comment: I found this rather more suit yo [security.se] where most of your points has answer. Besides, it is becoming more and more to use PAKE's https://soatok.blog/2022/12/29/what-we-do-in-the-etc-shadow-cryptography-with-passwords/

Comment: It is not clear about _add a multiple of the modulus_ on RSA part. Isn't the server holds $(e,n)$ as public key of the user? Yes, this is public key, $e$ is just the public exponent,

Comment: According to your title, I guess that you aim to find a method for generating an encrypted file that incorporates a password. In fact, Hash + salt is well-studied technique, and it is much faster than public-key based methods. Maybe I do not get the problem point you wanna solve.

Comment: I'm trying to solve password file leaks, so that it doesn't matter if a password file is leaked. But the method descripbed doesn't work :(

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://00f.net/2018/10/18/on-user-authentication/) blog post. Also, have you read into FIDO2 and passkeys?